# Get the index of the element

Tags: jquery, indexing

I have a code into the textarea. Here it is http://clip2net.com/s/2tnj2
When i click to submit button, all this code put into the variable.

```
$('#fc-send2').live('click',function () {

var code = $('textarea.site-code').val();

alert($(code).find('li').index('.my-class')); });
```

But it allways show me "-1". That mean, element not found.
How to find index of the element from variable "code".

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
var code = $('textarea.site-code').val();
```

Use

```
var code = $('textarea.site-code');
```

Comment: `var code = $('textarea.site-code');` return me "Object object"

Comment: @user1800796 What you are trying is bit unclear , can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @user1800796 this Object contains the element,it means it founds the element.Now you can perform what you want next to find

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 

$('#fc-send2').live('click',function () {

var code = $('textarea.site-code');

alert($(code).find('li').index('.my-class')); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ($() has been added to index)

```
alert($(code).find('li').index($('.my-class')));
```

**Update:** [Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/BrrblK/3NdXc/)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line

```
var code = $('textarea.site-code');
```

with

```
var code = $('#textarea.site-code');
```

you have just missed the `#` with the Id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fc-send2').live('click',function () {

  var code = $('textarea.site-code').val();
```

// code var is a String, not a DOM element

```
  alert($(code).find('li').index('.my-class'));
```

// that's why you can't do .find here

```
});
```

You should

```
var someHiddenContainer = $("#some-hidden-container");

someHiddenContainer.html( code ); //insert your code var to DOM

alert( someHiddenContainer.find("li").index(".my-class") );

someHiddenContainer.empty(); //optional
```

Comment: It was a backup plan.I want to do without the hidden container

Comment: Then use regular expression to match all the <li*> and get the index of element that matches 'class="my-class"'.